# Can I stop Sharepoint from wrapping my reusable content in <span> tags?

Tags: reusable-content

I am creating reusable content blocks for site editors to add to page content but Sharepoint has a nasty habit of taking my pristine HTML and wrapping it in completely unnecessary `<span>` tags.

In my case it is making basic CSS selectors like `.panel + .panel` impossible without run-time JavaScript hacks to unwrap elements.

Is it possible to configure Sharepoint so it **does not** add these `<spans>`?